# PHP libreria escpos-php. Tengo problema con ghostscript al momento de imprimir

Tags: php

estoy utilizando la libreria escpos-php para impresion de tickets, como aun no tengo la impresora fisicamente conmigo, decidi ir haciendo pruebas.

1. Instale por composer la libreria.
2. La importo a mi controllador y uso la misma.
3. Me descargue el programa Bullzip PDF Printer para instalar el emulador de impresión.

Mi controller:

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;

```
class Vender extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        //Carga modelo
        $this->load->model('Producto');
        $this->load->model('Ventas');

    }

// Función para imprimir el ticket
    function imprimirTicket() {
        try {
             // Creación de la instancia de Printer
            $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("Bullzip PDF Printer");

            $printer = new Printer($connector);

            // Encabezado del ticket
            $printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_CENTER);
            $printer->text("Mi tienda\n");
            $printer->text("123 Main St\n");
            $printer->text("Ciudad, Estado 12345\n");
            $printer->text("-----------------------------\n");

            // Cuerpo del ticket
            $printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_LEFT);
            $printer->text("Cantidad    Producto    Precio\n");
            $printer->text("-----------------------------\n");
            $printer->text("1           Producto 1  $10.00\n");
            $printer->text("2           Producto 2  $20.00\n");
            $printer->text("-----------------------------\n");
            $printer->text("Subtotal:               $30.00\n");
            $printer->text("Impuestos:               $1.50\n");
            $printer->text("Total:                  $31.50\n");

            // Pie del ticket
            $printer->text("-----------------------------\n");
            $printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_CENTER);
            $printer->text("Gracias por su compra!\n");

            // Corte de papel y cierre de conexión
            $printer->cut();
            $printer->close();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Manejo de excepciones
            echo "No se pudo imprimir el ticket: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

Hasta aca todo bien, el nombre de la impresora es el correcto, ya que abre el programa, pero con un error:

Ha ocurrido un error.

```
Error 1007: An error occurred while running Ghostscript

Error: /undefined in @aMi
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1990   1   3   %oparray_pop   1989   1   3   %oparray_pop   1977   1   3   %oparray_pop   1833   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:771/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 8


Source: GUI

Internal hint: Run converter to create PDF file
Developers: You can hide this message with the "suppreserrors" setting.
```

En base a éste error, volvi a instalar Ghostscript, mire las variables de entorno y estan bien, ejecuto el .exe del simbolo del sistema y Ghostscript esta instalado correctamente. La verdad que no se que puede ser.

EDIT: También probe con PDFCreator, y tampoco funciona

EDIT2: y si coloco la impresora Microsoft Print to PDF sale el error:
**Message: copy(\DESKTOP-G6B36S6\Microsoft Print to PDF): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

Answer (score 0):

El código que me compartiste tiene un error en la función imprimirTicket(). El error se debe a que la clase WindowsPrintConnector no está definida. Para solucionar este problema, debes asegurarte de que la clase esté definida en tu código o que hayas importado la biblioteca necesaria. Además, es posible que debas verificar que el nombre de la impresora sea correcto y que la impresora esté conectada y configurada correctamente. Si necesitas más ayuda, por favor házmelo saber.

https://sl.bing.net/hhOgGKfNBG8

Comment: Lee [Por qué publicar respuestas generadas por GPT y ChatGPT actualmente no es aceptable](/help/gpt-policy) y [La IA generativa (ChatGPT y similares) está prohibida](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5462). Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.